# count number of times checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a code where I want to check the number of times a checkbox is selected, if its greater than a certain number than a certain message will be displayed.  Problem is its not counting the number of times the checkbox is checked.

A sample of the checkboxes are as follows:

```
<div class="column" style="background-color: #b0a9de;">
        <h3>Favorite drink?</h3>
        <label class="container">V8
            <input name="1" type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container">Capri Sun
            <input name="2" type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container">Gatorade
            <input name="3" type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container">N/A
            <input name="4" type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

and the script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checked() {
        var coolPoints = document.getElementsByName("3").checked;
        if (coolPoints > 5)
            alert("You are a cool person!")
        else
            alert("You are an uncool person!");
    }


</script>
```

Whenever I have more than 5 selected of checkboxes with input name "3", it doesn't show the correct alert message.  I will always get the second alert.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to write the logic for keeping track of how often the checkbox gets checked or unchecked, there is nothing in your code doing that

Comment: I am unsure whether you want to get the total number of checked items or the total number that a certain item has been checked

Comment: You need 2 things. First you need to trigger your function when the check box is clocked.  In the input add on click=“checked();”.  Second, you need to move the counter variable outside the function so it isn’t reset each time the function is called. The. Increment it with += document... so I guess you need 3 things.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("3")` returns a collection, it doesn't have a checked property.

Answer (score 1):

onchange attribute on the input tag calls the function inside of it (onChange()) every time the checkbox value changes (whenever it's changed from checked to unchecked or vice-versa)

the onChange function checks if the the input element is checked (I got it from the queryQuelector - checkbox variable

AFTER checking, the same function checks the count number, if it reached 5 it alerts the user

```html
 <body>
    <input id="myid" type="checkbox" onchange="onChange()" />
  </body>
  <script>
    let count = 0;
    let checkbox = document.querySelector('#myid');

    function onChange() {
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        count++;
      }
      if (count >= 5) {
        alert("myalert")
      }
      console.log(count);
    }
  </script>
```

For multiple checkboxes case I used querySelectorAll to get ALL the checkboxes on the page ([type=checkbox]) square brackets are for attribute selection.

It puts them in the variable checkboxes as a list (or something similar to an array, I don't remember specifically), so the "list" has the same length as the number of checkboxes on the page.

Having N checkboxes, and wanting to have track of all of them, you have to make N counters, thats what "Array.from({ length: checkboxes.length }).map(() => 0);" makes in a coincise way, you could've just initialized the array as [0,0,0,0,0,0] otherwise, or with some different for loop on the checkboxes

The function in this case take an index as input (as you can see from the html every input element has a different number inside the function call, which refers to it's index in the array eventually)

The function does the same thing as before, but having to select the counter and the element inside an array, it uses the index

For the specific case of checking only 1 item I made the example "if (idx === 3)" which checks if the index of the element it's the one you specifically wanted before going to alert, in the example case, the alert will only work for the element which has function call with the 3. But all the others will still be having counters in case you need to do something with them as well

```html
 <body>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="onChange(0)" />
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="onChange(1)" />
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="onChange(2)" />
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="onChange(3)" />
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="onChange(4)" />
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="onChange(5)" />
  </body>
  <script>
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
    let counts = Array.from({ length: checkboxes.length }).map(() => 0);

    function onCheck(idx) {
      if (checkboxes[idx].checked) {
        counts[idx]++;
      }
      if(idx === 3 && counts[idx] >= 5) {
        alert("checkbox 3 alert")
      }
      console.log(counts[idx]);
    }
  </script>
```

Make a comment below if I haven't understood correctly, I'll fix it

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. You should explain why the OP has their issue and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! this works.  Anyway to make it so onChange will only count for one check per checkbox?

Comment: I'll add explanation to the answer :^D